# How to undo branch push to master

Tags: git, github, git-svn, git-push, git-reset

Okay, so I have a forked repo on GitHub, and the upstream repo hasn't been updated since I forked it. Yesterday, I created a branch based from the very last upstream commit which was made before I forked the repo months ago.

I did a bad commit on the branch, so I tried to undo it by using `git push -f origin HEAD^:master` on my local instance of the branch, but as you can see, I forgot to change `master` to the name of the branch. So it ended up overwriting everything I've done on the master so far.

My question is, is there a way to undo this mess so I can get the master back in the state it was before this particular push?

I use TortoiseGit and TortoiseSVN a lot, and I can't see leftovers of anything I've done on the master before in any component of Git, however I can still see all my previous commits in the SVN trunk's history log. I don't have a clean local instance of the master in its previous state.

I've tried stuff like `git reset --hard <last good commit hash>` or `git push -f origin <last good commit hash>:master`, but it says that no commit with such hash exists. I can still access all the previous commits on GitHub from my browser history.

There is nothing downstream, so no worries about that.

Any tips?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, here's how I fixed it from the branch's local instance:

1. `git log --graph --oneline --all`   to retrieve the last good commit's hash
2. `git reset --hard <last good commit hash>`
3. `git push origin +master`

Comment: what does the "+" in : 3. git push origin +master ?

Comment: @Olivvv: force push to specified branch, same as `--force`

Answer (score 0):

Give `git reflog` a try.  It remembers old commit hashes that might have been lost if you have not done a `git gc`.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to help me, I force-pushed the local branch directly to the remote master, I don't have a local Git instance of the master itself. I have no idea on how to interact with the remote without having to push my local instances every time I change anything.

Comment: Okay, if I do `git log --graph --oneline --all`, I can actually see the tree that used to be the master branch, how do I switch back the master to it?